# How to populate a div with hover text in bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3, interaction

I am developing a geographical dashboard in bokeh. It is fairly easy to use hover tooltip in bokeh, however I want to populate a div when I hover on a field.

> Python version : 3.5.2
>
> Bokeh version : 0.13.0

**1. This is the main view of the dashboard.**

[image: Dashboard]

**2. Required output**

[image: Required Dashboard]

I want to add two interactions,

1. When I hover on a district, it should only populate the district name field.
2. When I click on a district, it should populate both the district name and info field(area, population, density).

**3. Data:**

[image: Data]

**4. Code:**

```
    from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, output_file
    from bokeh.models import (
        GeoJSONDataSource,
        HoverTool,
        LinearColorMapper,
        ColorBar,
        BasicTicker,
        PrintfTickFormatter,
        LogColorMapper,
        Range1d,
        Plot,
        Text
    )
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    import geopandas as gpd
        with open('/home/drogon/Desktop/Rescue-1122-project/punjab_districts(area_pop_den).geojson', 'r') as f:
            geo_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=f.read())
        
        df = gpd.read_file('/home/drogon/Desktop/Rescue-1122-project/punjab_districts(area_pop_den).geojson')
        print(df.density)
        density = df['density']
        
        colors = ['#000003', '#3B0F6F', '#8C2980', '#DD4968', '#FD9F6C']
        colors.reverse()
        color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=colors, low=density.min(), high=density.max())
        
        TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,save"
        
        p = figure(title="Punjab Districts", tools=TOOLS, x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None, width=800, height=800)
        p.grid.grid_line_color = None
        p.title.text_font_size = '30pt'
        
        p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_alpha=0.9, fill_color={'field': 'density', 'transform': color_mapper},
                  line_color='white', line_width=1, source=geo_source)
        
        
        hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
        hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
        hover.tooltips = [("District", "@district"),
                          ("Density", "@density"),
                          ("Area", "@area")]
        
        color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, major_label_text_font_size="10pt",
                             ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=8),
                             formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d"),
                             label_standoff=10, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
show(p)
```

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would downvote this question.  I'd like to do the same thing.

Comment: @greymatter I moved on to other projects, I found bokeh difficult to understand.